# Yum search package with flag of installation status?

Tags: yum

I use `yum search <some package>` and get the search result lists. Howerver I cannot distiguish between installed package and uninstalled package.
So I have to `yum install <some package>` one by one, as packages donot show installation status. This operation is not efficiency enough.
Does smart way exists?

Answer (score 0):

`yum info <package_name>` is one option. What specific information do you hope to get?